# How to show messages before rollback?

Tags: pgadmin

I want to test transaction like

```
begin;
delete from A;
delete from B where B.A in (select guid from A);
rollback;
```

and see how many records would be deleted. But in pgadmin I see only

```
ROLLBACK
Query returned successfully in 906 msec.
```

What to set to see how many records in both tables would this transaction delete?

Comment: Replace `DELETE` with `SELECT`?

Comment: Table B has foreign key from table a. B.A = A.guid. I want to see what will happen in transaction.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Long time no see this. The order is wrong deleting from B should be before A and I would just use selects with count(*) nowdays. It is always tricky, because there can be a lot of traffic going on and the result can change every second.